# hibernate generate_statistics change nanoseconds to seconds

Tags: java, hibernate

I have using hibernate StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener to show query response time

here is the log

```
2016-01-20 11:10:48.841  INFO 12769 --- [http-nio-8081-exec-1] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
  66145 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
  0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
  6081355 nanoseconds spent preparing 212 JDBC statements;
  14977371 nanoseconds spent executing 212 JDBC statements;
  0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
  0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
  0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
  0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
  0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
  0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Can we convert nanoseconds value to seconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it cant changed
here is the class file https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.java

they using System.nanoTime() to get the value and there is no additional config.

Comment: What a pitty. It's absolutely horrible to read / interpret compare this output right out of the box. Configuration to use seconds with decimals, or at least have some number grouping would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually it seems to be not that hard.

You can not extend or configure the default StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener, but simply re-implementing it and changing its output is easy, see: https://gist.github.com/icyerasor/4008f7a7e245326eb314795c769f47e7 (no guarantee the formatting is not *super* unperformant, change the logger to your needs and also note that format of decimal output might now be locale specific).

Now registering it: as a quick hack(?) I got away with:

```
sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getBaselineSessionEventsListenerBuilder().setAutoListener(IteratecStatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.class);
```

it does work. Can someone confirm that this is the right way to do it? Couldn't find any documentation on "setAutoListener".

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically one could implement ones own StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener logging seconds, and add it as a listener in the Hibernate event system. Doing this in practice has been extremely daunting for me, and so far I haven't been able to get the handles to the right objects within my Spring Boot app to add my own MyStatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.